# How to use params to filter database objects with Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm still a bit new to Node in general, so I'm sorry if this is noob question. My setup is Sailsjs + MongoDB.

I have a RESTful API controller set up to handle the "lab" collection in my DB.

Here is what I use in my controller to pull up all the objects in this collection when **/lab/** is used:

```
index: function (req, res, next) {
  Lab.find(function foundLabs(err, labs) {
    if (err) return next(err);
      res.view({
        labs: labs
      });
  });
},
```

In this collection there are fields for "site" and "lab" and I'd like to be able to filter what shows up with params like:

> /lab/:site
>
> /lab/:site/:lab

So if "**/lab/aq**" was pulled up it would get all objects in the AQ site and if "**/lab/aq/123**" was pulled up it would get the objects for the 123 lab in the AQ site.

I know this would likely be done with the **Lab.find** function, but I haven't been able to find any documentation which gives me an answer I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/routes.js` file you need to add a route with optional parameters:

```
'/findLabs/:site?/:lab?': 'LabController.findLabs'
// use a different route than 'lab' to avoid interfering with the blueprint routes
```

Then, in your `LabController.js`, if the requested url had `site` and/or `lab`, you will find them in `req.params`:

```
// when a request is sent to '/findLabs/aq/123':

findLabs: function(req, res, next) {
    sails.log(req.params) // {site: 'aq', lab: '123'}

    // you can use them to filter:
    var query = Lab.find();

    if (req.params.site) query.where({site: req.params.site});
    if (req.params.lab) query.where({lab: req.params.lab});

    query.exec(function(err, labs) {
        if (err) return res.serverError();

        res.json(labs);
    });
}
```